# Clear all content from columns containing values after a cell containing certain value, vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to vba and just got stuck. I have a spreadsheet containing information from A1 to BW50. Cell AM7 contains certain value = (lets say) "Mytext". I want to write a code that will find the value and clear all columns that go after the column that contains this specific text. I know I could "fix" the columns and clear them but those columns might change as well as the location of the "Mytext" after which I want everything cleared. I cannot figure anything out. Any ideas please?

Thank you

Comment: Loop through Cells looking for "MyText" and then clear all the following columns. Which part in particular are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the find method will probably be the fastest:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clear()

Dim rng As Range
Dim str As String

str = "text"
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=str, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Range(Columns(rng.Offset(0, 1).Column), Columns(rng.Offset(0, 1).Column).End(xlToRight)).Delete
Else
    MsgBox "The value '" & str & "' was not found."
End If

End Sub
```

**Note:** `LookAt:=xlWhole` should be changed to `LookAt:=xlPart` if you are looking for any part of a text rather than the whole cell value.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian, can you explain me the range in the if statement? How can you set Row part of the Range to Column?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Will you please clarify? Also, if my answer worked for you, please accept as answer. :-)

Comment: Sorry, totally new member to this site. I mean this part: Range(Columns(rng.Offset(0, 1).Column), Columns(rng.Offset(0, 1).Column).End(xlToRight)).Delete... I understand it deletes the entire column, but I do not understand the logic. Does it mean that it offsets all the columns starting one after "my text" to the last column that has value? and then deletes all of them?

Comment: `rng.Offset(0, 1)` means it offsets 0 rows and 1 column from rng. `.Column` is the column property of `rng.Offset(0, 1)`. `.End(xlToRight)` is the last column in the row. And the whole thing is wrapped in `Range()`. Essentially, I am getting the range from the first column after `rng` to the last populated column.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearColumns()
    Dim f As Range
    Dim textToFind As String: textToFind = "Mytext"

    With Worksheets("mySheet").Range("A1:BW50") '<--| change "mySheet" with your actual sheet name
        Set f = .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Find(What:=textToFind, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False) '<--| look for text in given range cells withtext values
        If Not f Is Nothing Then .Range(f.Offset(, 1), .Columns(.Columns.Count)).Resize(.Rows.Count).ClearContents '<--| if text found then clear given range columns at the right of the found text
    End With
End Sub
```